# Exercise 10 in 1.1 (page 4) of Topology and Groupoids, by Ronald Brown

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

I searched for "Exercise 10 Topology and Groupoids" but didn't find anything relevant.

**Problem:**

Let $A_1 = [-1, 1) \setminus \{ 0 \}, A_2 = \{ 2 \}, A_3 = \mathbb{Q} \cap [3, 4]$, and let $A = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3$. Show that exactly fourteen distinct subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ may be constructed from $A$ by means of the operations Int (meaning interior) and complementation with respect to $\mathbb{R}$.

**Question:**

The way I see it, there are seven ways to apply complementation to $A$, and seven ways to apply Int to $A$, since $\sum_{j = 1}^3 \binom{3}{j} = 7$. There are therefore $7 \cdot 7 = 49$ different ways of applying Int and complementation to $A$. (Or maybe it's actually $98$ ways, since the interior and complement don't necessarily commute.)

Am I really expected to investigate all the possibilities and then notice that there are only 14 unique outcomes? This seems extremely tedious and not particularly illuminating of anything important.

Is there a quicker way to do this exercise? Or some sort of realization I'm supposed to have? Or is it just a bunch of busy work?

Below is my attempt, for what it's worth. I've rewritten $A_1$ as $[-1, 0) \cup (0, 1)$.

**My attempt:**

1.

\begin{align*}
A^c &= (A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3)^c\\
&= A_1^c \cap A_2^c \cap A_3^c\\
&= \big[ (-\infty, -1) \cup \{ 0 \} \cup [1, \infty) \big] \cap \big[ (- \infty, 2) \cup (2, \infty) \big] \cap \big[ \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \cup (- \infty, 3) \cup (4, \infty) \big]\\
&= (-\infty, -1) \cup \{ 0 \} \cup [1, 2) \cup (2, 3) \cup \big[ \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}  \cap (3, 4) \big] \cup (4, \infty).
\end{align*}

2.

\begin{align*}
\text{Int} A &= \text{Int} (A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3)\\
&= (-1, 0) \cup (0, 1).
\end{align*}

3.

\begin{align*}
(\text{Int} A)^c &= \big[ (-1, 0) \cup (0, 1) \big]^c\\
&= (- \infty, -1] \cup \{ 0 \} \cup [1, \infty).
\end{align*}

4.

\begin{align*}
\text{Int} (A^c) &= \text{Int} \big[ (-\infty, -1) \cup \{ 0 \} \cup [1, 2) \cup (2, 3) \cup \big[ \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}  \cap (3, 4) \big] \cup (4, \infty) \big]\\
&= (-\infty, -1) \cup (1, 2) \cup (2, 3) \cup (4, \infty).
\end{align*}

Comment: Did your googling lead you to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_closure-complement_problem ?

Comment: @AnginaSeng No, it didn't. The book doesn't mention anything about that, so I'm not sure how I would have found it. I guess the Kuratowski problem also applies when considering interiors and complements? I'm wondering if I should just go ahead and study the general problem rather than muddle through all the possibilities with this exercise.